# How do you zoom to bounding box using Xamarin Maps?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, maps

I have a Xamarin Android map (VS2019) and a number of lat/long points. What I want to do is have the map zoom in (or out), given a set of coordinates that set a bounding box.

I have this code (below) which doesn't seem to do anything. I've read all the documentation which suggests it should work but doesn't. I have checked and the bounding box coordinates are set correctly but the map doesn't do anything.

According to the docs calling `LayOut` should make it update but it doesn't do anything, no errors, just nothing.

How do I achieve this, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    MyMap.Layout(GetBounds(points));

    private Rectangle GetBounds(List<Point> points)
    {
        var minx = (from x in points select x.X).Min();
        var maxx = (from x in points select x.X).Max();
        var miny = (from x in points select x.Y).Min();
        var maxy = (from x in points select x.Y).Max();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(minx, miny, maxx - minx, maxy - miny);

        return rectangle;

    }
```

Comment: you set the Map's Camera - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did

I created a rectangle with the bounds where I need them

```
Rectangle rectangle = GetBounds(points);
```

Then I got the rectangle location

```
Position p1 = new Position(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y);
Position p2 = new Position((rectangle.X + rectangle.Width), (rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height));
```

... and then got the center point of the rectangle

```
double x = rectangle.X + (rectangle.Width / 2);
double y = rectangle.Y + (rectangle.Height / 2);
```

Then called `.MoveToRegion` using that data, and it works

```
        MyMap.MoveToRegion(
            MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(x, y), Distance.BetweenPositions(p1, p2))
        );
```